# How to show multiple slider in a page

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I apologize for asking the question if it was repeated, But I'm new here on web development,
I have used the code from w3schools for multiple slider on same page

```
var slideIndex = [1,1];

    /* Class the members of each slideshow group with different CSS classes */
    var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
    showSlides(1, 0);
    showSlides(1, 1);
    
    function plusSlides(n, no) {
      showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n, no) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";
    }
```

This is the script but I add additional slider id to slideId var like mySlides3, mySlides4, mySlides5, mySlides6, mySlides7

```
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
```

The slide is not working for myslide3 to myslides7
Because the first slides contain arrows

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
```

and second contains

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
```

If I repeat them they are working for myslide3 to 7

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I"ve found the solution in the script I have added the extra 1 for each extra mySlider class.

```
<script>
var slideIndex = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
/* Class the members of each slideshow group with different CSS classes */
var slideId = ["mySlides", "mySlides1", "mySlides2","mySlides3", "mySlides4", "mySlides5" , "mySlides6"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1,2);
showSlides(2, 3);
showSlides(3, 4);
showSlides(4,5);  
showSlides(5,6);
function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

and for the right and left arrow with continue scroll, I've added the respective class name number like myslide2 then used 2 and for myslide3 used 3 number along with 1 for next

```
<div class="arrows"><a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-2, 2)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">❯</a>
```

With this single script my all slider in a single page work as a continue slider